# Convert WebView to PDF

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, pdf-generation

I'm trying to take a WebView and convert it to a PDF. I've got the code working to convert the view to an image but would rather have a PDF.

```
public void ConvertToPDF(UIWebView webView)
{
    RectangleF canvasRect =  view.Bounds;
    CGPDFInfo info = new CGPDFInfo();
    info.AllowsPrinting = true;
    UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext (Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"MyDocument.PDF"), canvasRect, info);
    UIGraphics.BeginPDFPage ();
    CGContext gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

    view.Layer.RenderInContext (ctx);

    UIGraphics.EndPDFContent ();
}
```

All I get with above code is a blank pdf.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: can you please post the code of converting webview to image for me that is not working

Answer (score 0):

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocument, 1);

```
UIImage *pageImage = [PDFPageConverter convertPDFPageToImage:page withResolution:144];
NSString *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:destinationPath];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(pageImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

this code will do the stuffs
just pass CGPDFDocument object and page number to function
or 
download example from below link
http://ipdfdev.com/2011/04/22/convert-an-image-to-pdf-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/